# how to change angular stepper progress color when next step active

Tags: css, angular, typescript

i am trying to do a progression stepper as shown in this image  [image]

this is my code in css

```
.mat-step-header[aria-selected="true"] {
    background-color: #07C496;
}
.mat-step-header[ng-reflect-active='true']{
    background-color: #07C496;
 }
```

html :

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper labelPosition="bottom" linear >
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit" let-index="index"> {{index + 1}}
    </ng-template>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>test</ng-template>
        <div>
    </mat-step>
<mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>test</ng-template>
        <div>
    </mat-step>
<mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>test</ng-template>
        <div>
    </mat-step>
<mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>test</ng-template>
        <div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

this thing works in developement mode only and but doesn't work in prod mode cause ng-reflect-active doesnt exists in prod mode. can anyone help me to do this in css only pls.

Comment: you can try `ng-deep` https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Comment: How do you determine the progress? We need to see more (at least about the html) to tell, what is possible.

Comment: @enno.void it wont work cause the ng-reflect-active does not exist in prod mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate *select all elements before* behavior with the help of [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`) :

```
.mat-step-header {
    background-color: #07C496 !important;
}

.mat-step-header[aria-selected="true"] ~ * {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fvcuez?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)**